# Solving a 2nd-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

My equation is

```
[{x[t]*x'[t])'-(F/m)+(b/m)*x(t)*x'(t)==0},x(0)=0,x'(0)=0]
```

It is a form of Newtons momentum equation, but I am having a lot of trouble solving this in Mathematica. Is DSolve the correct method to go about this?

Comment: Please describe the underlying mechanical problem a little bit more.

Comment: Please see [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)

Comment: To answer your question, `DSolve` is the first function to try in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about the initial conditions?

DSolve is the right method. Observing that only the product `x[t]x'[t]` occurs the substitution `x[t]x'[t]->u[t]` gives a first order ode which can be solved for u[t]

```
U = DSolveValue[ {D[u[t] , t] - (F/m) + (b/m)*u[t] == 0  }, u, t]
(*Function[{t}, F/b + E^(-((b t)/m)) C[1]]*)
```

Resubstituting u[t] gives the solution x[t]

```
X = DSolveValue[{x[t] x'[t] == U[t]   }, x, t]
(*Function[{t}, -((Sqrt[2] Sqrt[F t - E^(-((b t)/m)) m C[1] + b C[2]])/Sqrt[b])]*)
```

That is the general solution of your problem! The parameters `C[1],C[2]` must be choosen to fullfill the initial conditions

```
{X[0], X'[0]}
(*{-((Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-m C[1] + b C[2]])/Sqrt[b]), -((F + b C[1])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b] Sqrt[-m C[1] + b C[2]]))}*)
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to adapt your initial conditions `x[0]==0,x'[0]==0`

Answer (score 1):

[Please](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroduction.html) [read](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) [these](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithDSolveIntroduction.html) [introductions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DifferentialEquations.html) [before](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html) continuing.  What appears to be the function you want is `DSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\((x[t]*\(x'\)[t])\)\) - (F/
      m) + (b/m)*x[t]*x'[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t]`, which has no solutions for your initial conditions.